# Submit post and get and receive the response page in ruby (external website)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, form-submit

I know to get a simple page I do:

```
require 'net/http'

source = Net::HTTP.get('example.com', '/index.html')
```

But how do I make a post from a form and get the page that returns the results of the data submitted? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

According to Net::HTTP doc you can do

```
res = Net::HTTP.post_form("example.com/index.html", 'q' => 'ruby', 'max' => '50')
puts res.body
```

see http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-post_form

Answer (score 1):

An really easy way is to use the [resttclient](https://github.com/adamwiggins/rest-client) gem:

```
require 'rest_client'
result = RestClient.post 'http://example.com/resource', :param1 => 'one'
```